# Comparison of 2 JSON file using jq in bash storing difference in another json or text file

Tags: bash, shell, sh, jq

I have 2 json files.

test1.json

```
{
"GeoIP.x86_64":"1.5.0-14.el7",
"NetworkManager.x86_64":"1:1.18.0-5.el7_7.1",
"NetworkManager-libnm.x86_64":"1:1.18.0-5.el7_7.1",
"NetworkManager-ppp.x86_64":"1:1.18.0-5.el7_7.1"
}
```

test2.json

```
{
"GeoIP.x86_64":"1.5.0-14.el7",
"NetworkManager.x86_64":"1:2.18.0-5.el7_7.1",
"NetworkManager-libnm.x86_64":"1:1.19.0-5.el7_7.1",
"NetworkManager-ppp.x86_64":"1:1.19.0-5.el7_7.1",
"gcc" : "1:1.9.0-el7_7.1"
}
```

The above JSON may or not have same package, I want to create a new 2 json like this with above json:

```
{
"NetworkManager.x86_64":"1:2.18.0-5.el7_7.1",
"NetworkManager-libnm.x86_64":"1:1.19.0-5.el7_7.1",
"NetworkManager-ppp.x86_64":"1:1.19.0-5.el7_7.1",
"gcc" : "1:1.9.0-el7_7.1"
}
```

The key = **NetworkManager-libnm.x86_64** , **NetworkManager.x86_64** and **NetworkManager-ppp.x86_64** has different value in test2.json and **gcc** is new package. So these 3 packages comes to final json.

I want to achieve this in shell script with help jq.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: NetworkManager.x86_64 also has a different value from the examples given.

Comment: To expand upon this you're probably best to just do a simple diff / awk and then parse the output for leading / trailing commas and insert as necessary. e.g. ` awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a)' test1.json test2.json` or ` diff <(jq -S . test1.json) <(jq -S . test2.json)`

Comment: @bobdylan sorry, I missed it. Updating question.

Comment: @bobdylan, diff will also show those values which is in test1.json but not in test2.json

Comment: You can use grep -vf instead. But the awk will be the most performant

Answer (score 1):

```
jq -n --argfile one test1.json --argfile two test2.json '
   $test2 | with_entries( select($test1[.key] != .value) )'
```

or if you want to add the key functionality to your jq library, the key abstraction is:

```
   def minusObject(o1;o2):
     o1 | with_entries( select(o2[.key] != .value) );
```

Comment: Hi Peak thanks for answering.
I want to build a single json by test1.json and test2.json
{
 "TIMESTAMP1":{
  "After": <test1.json>,
  "before": <test2.json>
 },
 "TIMESTAMP2":{
  "After": <test1.json>,
  "before": <test2.json>
 }
}

If file exist, we need to append new TIMESTAMP Key with new test1 and test2 json

Its it possible with jq

Comment: Without seeing your detailed requirements, I'm not sure exactly how to approach your problem but it certainly seems that jq could be part of a good solution.  I would suggest you ask a separate SO question, in accordance with the [mcve] guidelines.

Comment: Question Asking Limit Exceed:

But I wrote jq like this:
jq -n --argfile a test1.json --argfile b test2.json --arg TIMESTAMP "$TIMESTAMP" '. + { "'$TIMESTAMP'" : {"After" : $a ,  "Before"
: $b } }' > test.json

It is working fine but I am not getting how to add new key to existing JSON